# Static File for Image doesn't work from javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show a certain image (checkmark or "X") based on a variable. When I load the image from a script within the HTML file, it works fine. When I try to set the image from within the createEasyDiag function, it comes back as undefined. When I test with a url based image, it works fine.

```
<div class="top" id="easyDiag"> 
                <div class="easyDiag"><div class="top">DnsStatus </div><img id="dnsStatus" class="easyDiagImg"/></div>                
                <script type="text/javascript">                        
                    
                    const img = document.getElementById("dnsStatus");
                    img.src = "{{url_for('static', filename='css/greencheck.png')}}"
                    // img.src = "https://picsum.photos/200/301"; // url img works

                    createEasyDiag(tables) // this is the function id like the two lines above to be in.
                   
                </script>
            </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is this `{{ }}` supposed to do? Do you use a template engine of some kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was much simpler than I was trying to make it. My solution was using the following lines.

```
const img = document.getElementById("dnsStatus");
img.src = "/static/css/greencheck.png";
```